# validate a 10 digit USA style phone number using a Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a 10 digit USA style phone number using a Regular Expression in Javascript

It should allow (validate as correct) the following formats:

```
xxx-xxx-xxxx

215-121-1247
```

It should reject as invalid:

```
8059311142
805 931 42ab
105 931 4288
```

I found a regex to implement this below, but I can't get it to work.

```
/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/
```

please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very simply do it as:

`^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jV1hP3

To understand what your `regex` is doing, check [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%5C%28%3F%28%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%29%5C%29%3F%5B-.+%5D%3F%28%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%29%5B-.+%5D%3F%28%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%29%24)